# What are "advance articles" and how to cite them?

Tags: citation-style

I noticed some journals are publishing advance articles that are not part of a published volume (i.e. https://academic.oup.com/isr/advance-articles).

I am a bit confused in regards to what is the status of these publications. Will advance articles be part of future volumes or will they remain standalone? Also, how would you cite them in Chicago 17 given the lack of issue and volume numbers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Some journals publish preliminary versions of articles.** The final version will appear in a published volume, the preliminary version might not, since changes may be made.

You can cite a preliminary version, just like you would cite any manuscript. You cannot list issue/volume numbers, because they don't exist. You could label such manuscripts as "preliminary" or "to appear" or "advance article" or "advance article, final version to appear" ...